# JS: Counting frequency of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-operator

I am practicing counting the frequency of unique elements in an array using this function, which I found here on StackOverflow:

```
let numArray = [1,3,8,10,39,67,88,12,11,9,1,8,1,8]
let countFrequency = function(arr){
     var counts = {};
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          var num = arr[i];
          counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
          }
console.log(counts)
}
```

and then calling the function like so:

```
countFrequency(numArray);
```

And the result is this: {"1":3, "3":1, "8":3,...etc} which is correct and the desired behaviour.

However. I have no idea why this works and what is happening 'under the hood'. This is a common solution here on StackOverflow for this type of problem, but I can't find a clear explanation of this line:

```
counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
```

I know this is a ternary operator and how the operator itself works, but cannot for the life of me understand how it is building the 'counts' object. Could anyone please explain exactly how this solution works, or point me in the direction of an article that explains this? I think this would be useful for others who are learning this technique too, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to read a property which does not exist it returns `undefined`, which is falsey in javascript. So, with that in mind lets expand the ternary to a longhand `if` statement

```
if(counts[num]){
   counts[num] = counts[num] + 1;
}
else {
   counts[num] = 1
}
```

Hopefully that makes it clearer what is going on, in pseudocode

```
if counts[num] has previously been set
   add one to counts[num]
otherwise
   set counts[num] to 1
```

One other thing that might have thrown you is the [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) for reading properties. In javascript both `myObject.foo` and `myObject["foo"]` are equivalent.

Comment: for exists, the reprensentation is `in`. you need to introduce *falsy* ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, didn't understand your comment.

Comment: `counts[num]` could be `undefined` as value or as state, or any other falsy value, or any other truthy value. the check for an existing key is `in` (i think, you know it all, but the answer does not represent this)

Comment: @NinaScholz technically correct. In this specific case/piece of code we equate truthiness with the existance of the value, as we don't expect any falsy values; only `undefined` when the value is absent. So `counts` either doesn't contain `num` or it contains a truthy value for `num`. And I agree with you that this distinction is important and a JS programmer should be introduced to it. Im just not sure if this doesn't go too much beyond the scope of this question.